# Select in socket c++ doesn't work

Tags: c++, c, sockets, select

I created a class that implements the select function of the tcpsocket.
(listenSock is a vector of TcpSocket - that works)
I dont understand why but the second time select is called the program stop working.

```
TCPSocket* MultipleTCPSocketsListener::listenToSocket(){
    //TODO: create local set for the select function (fd_set)
    fd_set set;
    FD_ZERO (&set);
    FD_SET (0, &set);

    //TODO: fill the set with file descriptors from the socket list using (FD_SET macro)
    for ( int i = 0; i < listenSock.size(); i++ )
    {
        FD_SET (listenSock.at(i)->getSock(), &set);
    }

    //TODO: perform the select
    int sel=select(sizeof(set)*8,&set,NULL,NULL,NULL);

    //TODO: check the returned value from the select to find the socket that is ready
     if (sel==-1) {
          perror("select failed");
          return NULL;
     }

    //TODO: if select return a valid socket return the matching TCPSocket object otherwise return NULL
     if (sel > 0)
     {
         for ( int i = 0; i < listenSock.size(); i++ )
         {
             if (FD_ISSET(listenSock.at(i)->getSock(), &set)) return  listenSock.at(i);
         }
     }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FD_SET (0, &set);
```

is useless. You instruct select to treat stdin as one of the sockets to watch.

Comment: so what should i do instead? or just delete this line?

Comment: exactly. Just delete it.

Comment: Why do you think that 0 is the stdin and not a null socket descriptor?

Comment: `fd 0` is `stdin` - one of the many, many things one will have to know about linux. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor

Comment: @o_weisman: Because I have seen more questions of users without a proper name, and according to my experience, the do not tend to do things intentionally. Thus I think the best way to help him is: Assume he did that unintentionally, and show how correct it.

Comment: @HansKlünder I was only asking what specializt answered above

Comment: That's perfectly fine, o_weisman. And I tried to answer that question.

Comment: By the way, does Linux ignore the first parameter to select() same as Windows?

Comment: I don't know. I never was aware of the fact that Windows ignores it. In all my code, it makes no difference because my sets do not contain any sockets above the first parameter to select(). Thus I never saw any effects that would show me that Windows ignores it.

Comment: @HansKlünder Well, he/she is sending in the size of the set*8 which doesn't seem to be much of a guarantee. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right, that is a part of the code which I do not like at all, and he might ask for help because of that later. However, he uses FS_ZERO, thus for now it won't matter it the first parameter is too high, except if it exceeds the total size of the set, which it won't. It just slows down the program, but it introduces no errors. Also, I don't think the first parameter will be too small. Even if fd_set is just a small structure pointing to the real data, like std::vector, it will very likely be large enough to contain his sockets - their file descriptors are not big in Linux.